# Why not have an identical cookie for different user's devices?

Tags: php, mysql, security, cookies

Here is my table structure:

```
// users
+----+--------+------------------------+------------------+-------------------------------+
| id |  name  |          email         |     cookie       |    /* some other columns */   |
+----+--------+------------------------+------------------+-------------------------------|
| 1  | Jack   | jack0948@gmail.com     | ojer0f934mf2...  |                               |
| 2  | Peter  | P_2009@ymail.com       | ko4398f43043...  |                               |
| 3  | John   | mx_pro34@gmail.com     | 0243hfd348i4...  |                               |
+----+--------+------------------------+------------------+-------------------------------+
```

**`cookie`** column contains a string *(as the cookie which keeps the user logged)* that is also set into user's devices. As you see, I have just **one** string *(as the cookie)* for each user. So all user's devices have an identical cookie.

---

**What's my question:** The most of professional programmer tell me:

> It would be safer if each device had its own cookie (the cookie of each device should be different than the cookie of other devices, not a constant cookie for all devices)

Well why? What's wrong with having an identical cookie for all devices? Also as you see I have just one record for the cookie in the database. So if I update that record for new device, then the previous device(s) will be log out.

Comment: How do you prevent session hijacking with that?

Comment: @CD001 What? I think session is nothing to do with having an identical cookie for all devices.

Comment: Say Jack is on an open WiFi and I "eavesdrop" and copy his cookie across to my phone and visit your site, how does it know I'm *not* Jack?

Comment: @CD001 `:-)` fair enough ..! However, the possibility of what you said happening is pretty low.

Comment: Even so - that's pretty much the definition of session hijacking; a log in should be tied to a single device with some kind of fingerprint/token system for the duration of the session only - using a cookie with both `secure` and `httpOnly` flags set. That's probably why most professionals are telling you it's *"safer if each device had its own cookie"*

Comment: @CD001 I see. Well may you please write an answer under my question and explain me what table-structure do I need for that? *(and how should I generate a cookie?)*

Comment: So there are 2 different people by now asking you to set a different cookie per device: that is not a security good practice as they pretend but  an absolute non-sense bullshit for the reason I mentioned previously.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that by cookie, you mean session id. Cookies can represent anything actually.

You should never store a session id in the database. Session ids are temporary values that should change on each new session. By storing them, you expose yourself to several problems :

- session stealing : if someone finds out a session id he does not own, it will *always* be valid. This is wrong.
- collisions : I imagine you generate those values using a hash method of some kind. In that case, you can have collisions between to accounts having the same session id.
- - probably some other problems...

By having a session id generated on each new session, you avoid those problems. But this means that your devices may not have the same session id for the same user.

What you are actually doing here, by storing the session id, is **NOT** a session id. It's a password, stored in plain text. And that is **very wrong**.